# Check if gRpc server is running for Grpc.Net.Client

Tags: c#, grpc, rpc

This question is basically the same as [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62769135/check-if-grpc-server-is-running-in-c-sharp) but instead Grpc.Core I would use the more up to date library Grpc.Net.Client. The Channel class here has neither a property "State" nor a ConnectAsync() method nor any other method to detect the current connection state. My goal is to write a Server and a Client application where the startup order ist arbitrary, i.e. If the Client is started before the Server it shall wait until the Server and therefore the connection becomes ready.

Comment: Did you get the answer?